# Nested dictionary from API - in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a API, from which Iam trying to create a output as a nested json/dict.

API looks somehow like this:

```
{
            "skuNO": "SK0011 - Green Stator with Terminal Box",
            "toStationLocation": "Line 1 - Station 1",
            "quantity": "1",
        },
{
            "skuNO": "SK0011 - Green Stator with Terminal Box",
            "toStationLocation": "Line 1 - Station 2",
            "quantity": "1",
        },
{
            "skuNO": "SK0011 - Green Stator with Terminal Box",
            "toStationLocation": "Line 1 - Station 2",
            "quantity": "3",
        },
```

I want an output somewhat like this:

```
{
"Line 1 - Station 2": {"SK0011": 4}
"Line 1 - Station 1": {"SK0011": 1}
}
```

I tried a few things with zip and dict, but didnt get much success. My last attempt was until like this, which I know is a very bad attempt. But Iam running out of options.

```
final_dict = {}
for x in data:
        int_sku = []
        int_qty = []
        int_sku.append(x['skuNO'])
        int_qty.append(x['quantity'])
        zipped = dict(zip(int_sku, int_qty))
        if x['toStationLocation'] not in final_dict:
            final_dict[x['toStationLocation']] = zipped
        else:
            for key,val in final_dict.items():
                for k,v in val.items():
                    print(k,v)
                    if k == int_sku[0]:
                       v = int(int_qty[0]) + int(v)
```

**Note:** Any other option to create other object with the uniqueness of these 3 are also fine and welcomed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final_dict = {}
for data in test_data:
    key = data["toStationLocation"]
    sku = data["skuNO"].split()[0]
    quant = int(data["quantity"])
    
    if key not in final_dict:
        final_dict[key] = {sku: quant}
    elif sku not in final_dict[key]:
        final_dict[key][sku] = quant
    else:
        final_dict[key][sku] += quant
```

Comment: `data["skuNO"].split(maxsplit=1)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach, which uses `default` dict to simplify the logic and eliminates `if` statements:

```py
import collections

final_dict = {}
for datum in data:
    line_station = datum["toStationLocation"]
    sku = datum["skuNO"].split(" - ")[0]
    quantity = int(datum["quantity"])

    final_dict.setdefault(line_station, collections.defaultdict(int))
    final_dict[line_station][sku] += quantity
```

For the inner dictionary, I use a `collections.defaultdict(int)`, which will initialize the sku to 0 upon the first mention of it.